# Python typeerror 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm new to python so this is probably something I've just missed...
I'm just trying to run a file which calls another file.

I have a file like myfile.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import another_file

things = ... """ some code """

def mystuff(text, th=things):
    return another_def(text, th)
```

'`another_file`' can compile/run fine by itself and has the def '`another_def`' and the variable '`th`' (These are just example names...)

So I run `python` from the command line and then try:

```
>>> import myfile
>>> t = myfile.mystuff('some text')
```

and I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "myfile.py", line 18, in mystuff
    return another_def(text, th)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I tried `import another_file` even though it is in `myfile.py` but that didn't seem to make any difference.

If it makes any difference, I tried:

```
print myfile
<module 'myfile' from 'myfile.py'>
print myfile.mystuff
<function mystuff at 0x7fcf178d0320>
```

so I assume that if it can find file and function, the problem is how it tries to call the other file.... maybe. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the method code `myfile.mystuff` which seems to be problematic?

Comment: If you've changed the names to protect the innocent you've made this question hard to answer. A "Module not callable" error means you are trying to use a module as though it's a function.

Comment: @doctorlove I changed the names in the hope of making the problem seem easier (didn't work but oh well) - you were right actually, because in the original code the 'another_file' and 'another_def' have the same name.... sigh. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure *why* you're getting a `TypeError` (there's probably more to it than what you're showing), but if you want to access functions from `another_file`, then you should do:

```
return another_file.another_def(text, th)
```

Comment: that seemed to do it! I assumed that by importing the file that it would pick up the function names... *facepalm*

Comment: @dgBP Great to hear! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the so called wild import:

from other_file import *

And that way you can access all objects and functions in that file. Unless ofcourse, you have defined the

```
__all__
```

list wich restrict what can be exported.

Example:

```
#some_file.py

a = 3; b = 4 
__all__ = ['a']
```

now with the wild import:

```
from some_file import *
```

you only see 'a'